# jQuery - Get value of hyperlink.navigateurl

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I bind click to a series of `asp:hyperlink` via the following jquery

```
$(".dummyIdentifier").click(function () {
            $("#divLineItemComments").dialog("open");
            return false;
        });
```

This works fine.  Now, I need to pass the value of Hyperlink.NavigateUrl `OnClick`.  So that I may include the values with ajax `$.get()`

How can I get the value of a clicked hyperlink?  I do not know it's ID as the hyperlinks are generated dynamically along with their names by ASP.NET.

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Notes" ItemStyle-CssClass="NoMargin NoPadding" SortExpression="lineNotes">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink id="notesHl" runat="server" text='<%# Bind("lineNotes") %>' Font-Underline="true" Font-Bold="true" CssClass="dummyPhysicalNoteIdentifier"></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Font-Size="Smaller" Height="10px" Width="10px" Wrap="True" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(".dummyIdentifier").click(function () {
    $("#divLineItemComments").dialog("open");

    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    return false;
 });
```

Comment: +1 Pretty much. You can also just call `this.href` and avoid having to wrap your object again in jQUery.

Comment: haha yeh - jQuery is so ingrained in my js mindset now I tend to ALWAYS use it, sometimes to my detriment as in this case!